# gluon mobile iOS - textfield and spinner cause fxmlloader to throw fxml.loadexception when running on iPhone

Tags: ios, spinner, textfield, gluon-mobile

I am trying to include a charm.glisten.control.textfield or a spinner (FX8) to allow the user to input an integer value in an ios app. When running the app from the ide on Mac, both the textfield and spinner controls work as expected. However, when I deploy the app to my iPhone, the associated view will not load and I get the following message during gluonfx:nativerun:

`[Wed Feb 01 15:24:04 JST 2023][INFO] [SUB] IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException:  [Wed Feb 01 15:24:04 JST 2023][INFO] [SUB] /com/maplesunbook/views/calculator.fxml:139` 
The line number referenced in the error corresponds to the textfield (or spinner) tag in the FXML.

When I remove the textfield, the view loads and functions as expected.

I don't get any other errors when building or during deployment.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` before building the native image, and explore all possible scenarios of the application, so all uses of reflection are discovered. Then build and deploy again, the error should be gone.

Comment: @JoséPereda That solved the issue. Is it best practice to execute the gluonfx:runagent before building? What other kinds of errors can be fixed by executing gluonfx:runagent? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Most of the reflection uses of the JavaFX built-in controls are included by default by the GluonFX plugin, but not all. `runagent` is useful (but not 100% effective) to address the missing cases.